# How to reduce noise while recording sound in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hi guys i am developing an online audio recorder, i need to reduce the noise while recording the sound.How to achieve this?
My current audio format is

AudioFormat(8000.0F,16,1,true,false);

Comment: Have you found or build anything :) ?, i am highly interested to know .

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement some digital signal filters on your data. Depending on the kind of noise you're targeting, simple band pass filters might work, or you could go the whole hog and implement something like Dolby A/B

Comment: Can we have any example on Java Code please ? I am very interested on this .